# Cdrom is mounted, but where?

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, mount, filesystem, cd-drive

A Nautilus folder will be opened automatically when inserting a CD in a drive. It is under Devices with name Audiodisk. As long as the files are accessed via Nautilus everything is fine.

The problem is that I can not find the cdrom files from the File System. This means that I can not access the cdrom files directly from applications.

This is a problem in 12.10.

I have checked all subfolders in /media, /mnt and /cdrom and didn't find the cdrom content there.

mount and df commands do not show anything related to cdrom.

In /etc/fstab there is a line

> /dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0
>   0

But the cdrom files are not in /media/cdrom0, it seems empty.

Disks show the drive as

> Device /dev/sr0 (Read-Only)

When clicking a cdrom file in Nautilus and checking the properties it says under the Basic tab

> Location: cdda://sr0/

/etc/mtab commmand output

```
/dev/sda1 / ext3 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755 0 0
/dev/sda6 /home ext3 rw,relatime,user_xattr 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/s/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,user=s 0 0
```

How to find the mount point?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would be under `/run/user/s/gvfs` on the filesystem.

Another thing you can do is simply drag the file from Nautilus into the file open dialog of the application you want to open it in, or to a terminal. This should give you the full path to open with the classic POSIX methods for apps not using gvfs.

Although, if it is an Audio CD, it is likely not actually mounted. The underlying VFS support in GNOME/Nautilus just scans the disc and presents the tracks as raw wav files in the UI.

Comment: Thanks! I confirm that the location on the filesystem you indicated was correct. Also I confirm that drag and drop of a file to terminal will show the full path.   (Unfortunately drag and drop to applications like audacity doesn't seem to work.)  It would be nice to know what in the mtab line 'binfmt ...' tells it is related to cd-drive.

Comment: Ah the formatting of the mtab content was pretty messed up. I'm not sure exactly what the binfmt_misc filesystem is, but it's in-memory, and probably unrelated to the audio disc 'mounting' action.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the Nautilus properties you gave, that CD is an audio CD and not a CDROM - it's being detected as CDDA (CD Digital Audio) type, which is not a regular filesystem.  Since it isn't using the iso9660 filesystem, the line in /etc/fstab gets ignored.   The only way to view the contents of an audio CD is via a tool that understands CDDA format.